# How to add a reference to an EventReceiver back to SPLIst

Tags: development, event-receivers

I am using SP2013 On Prem. I use a third party solution that deploys custom lists to a site when activated. I need to remove the SPListItem ItemDeleting event receiver from this list, delete some items, and then re add this event receiver. This is in QA and we need a way to purge items during testing and the vendors event handler prevents this. This custom action will be used by 2 or 3 people in a non production farm.

I am able to add/remove EventReceivers(ER) using powershell without a problem but in C# it is not so clear to me how to add the ER back!

Prior to removal I store the Assembly, Class, Type and Name into a text file. In my AddEventReceiver function I want to retrieve these from the text file (easy part) and then readd the event handler to the list. I could always deactivate and reactivate the feature but I'm hoping for something more elegant (?).

Can someone show me how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Run inside SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges:

```
var list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"path to txt file")

SPEventReceiverDefinition sper = list.EventReceivers.Add();
sper.Assembly = lines[0];
sper.Class = lines[1];
sper.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemDeleting;
sper.Name = lines[3];
sper.Update();
list.Update();
```